# JSON Request is not configure with zap Authentication.

Tags: owasp, zap

I am using ZAP security testing tool.but at the point of Authentication by username and password of a JSON Request, I face problem to configure these. I checked all links and blogs too. but I can't get the proper step by step solution on it. 
Request code:-

```
{"userName":"cwc_patna","password":"33a0d2e93e0ad396b7c9374bbbc83a58"}
```

Response code:-

```
{"userId":72,"userName":"cwc_patna","password":"33a0d2e93e0ad396b7c9374bbbc83a58","emilId":"pratyush@sdrc.co.in","userTypeId":1,"viewName":"cwc","isLive":null,"isActive":null,"isApproved":null,"sjpuAccess":null,"userUserTypeFeaturePermissionMapping":null,"area":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

That functionality was only just added last week: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/pull/4624

If you want to use it, you'll either have to use a weekly: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads#zap-weekly

Or, wait for the next full release (likely 2.8.0).

The corresponding PR to update the help content for the new JSON Authentication functionality is here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/pull/188/files if you want to check it out.

You set it up the same way you would for form based authentication. Make sure you define a Logged-in or Logged-out Identifier (or both). Here's some screenshots to help you along:

Manually configure the Authentication for your Context:
[image: Context Authentication Settings]

Use the Site Tree Context menu(s) to set it up:
[image: Flag a JSON request as the Context's "Login Request"]

[image: Select the associated username and password fields]

Here's an additional help link that might assist you in getting authentication setup: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth

Comment: now, I am using new weekly release. can you please explain, how to use JSON Authentication.

Comment: Answer updated with screenshots and supplemental details.

Comment: BTW why does your response contain the password hash still? Is there some reason to pass that back to the user? That kind of seems like a mistake.